# What must I check after I got my new refurbished MacBook Pro 13"?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

My friend wants to buy new refurbished MacBoook Pro 13" mid 2014 MGX72 in Malaysia. He's afraid of defects. So he needs advice on how to check whether it has problem or not. If it has, he must report it as soon as possible to the Apple Reseller where he bought it in Malaysia, before going home to Indonesia.

I know this site is not for a question of which Mac I should buy, but I ask about technical advice on how to check a new refurbished MacBook Pro 13" after I got it, so if it has any problem I can detect it and report it soon, so I won't have any problems when I'm home.

What I currently know is only check whether the display doesn't have dead pixel, and checking the battery (is it running up to around 9-10 hours as promised and calibrate it).

What else should I test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer, start the MacBook and hold down the **D** key when you hear the startup chime. This will start the built-in diagnostics and any problems that are found will be listed here. Apple link [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18765?locale=en_US).